# How is it possible that $L_1$ is $NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, complexity-classes, sets

**The question is from my complexity-theory course.**

### The question

If $L_1,L_2,L_3 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^*$, and different from $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^*$ and from the empty language, prove that if $L_1 \leq_p L_2  \cap L_3$, where $L_2 \in NP$ and $L_3 \in P$ then $L_1 \in NP$

#### My answer

Due to the fact that $P \subseteq NP$, we know that $L_2 \in NP$ and that $L_1 \in P$. $L_2 \cap L_3$ is at most $L_3$ so $L_2 \cap L_3 \in P$ then I proved that $L_1 \in P$. But the question asks to prove that $L_1 \in NP$. Is it a joke? Am i missing something?

Comment: Your conclusion that $L_1 \in P$ is false in general (unless P=NP). Consider for example $L_1=L_2=SAT$ and $L_3 = \{0,1\}^*$. The error is in the step "$L_2 \cap L_3$ is at most $L_3$ so $L_2 \cap L_3 \in P$".

Comment: Sorry for mistaken $\in$ i used the wrong latex symbol, $L_3 \neq \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^*$

Comment: In that case, take $L_1=L_2 = \{0w : w \in SAT\}$ and $L_3 = \{0w : w \in \{0,1\}^*\}$.

Comment: It works as example. I need to prove basically that the intersection between an NP language and a P language is always in NP.

Comment: Right, this is the exercise. I suggest now spending a few more days on it.

Comment: Intersection has logically equivalent operation (which?) and that would give an answer, isn't it?

Comment: Due to the fact that it must be an interception between a $TM$ that accept $L3$ and an $NTM$ that accept $L2$. $L2 \cap L3$ must be in $NP$. Right?

Comment: Try to give a formal proof.

Comment: You can choose $L_2=SAT$ and $L_3=HornSAT$. Then you intersect them. Given language is $SAT$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your proof is faulty.  You claim "we know that $L_1 \in P$", but that doesn't follow.  You haven't justified that claim, and I don't think it's true. It's not clear why you think that would be true, so it's hard to say why you went astray, but that's the first step that is wrong.  Also "is at most $L_3$ is not well-defined, and the intersection of a language in $P$ and a language in $NP$ is not necessarily in $P$.

I think you need to be more careful with your proofs: you have multiple steps where you make claims that simply don't follow from the previous steps.  I recommend you justify each step much more carefully, in more detail -- and if you can't, you should be suspicious of whether it is actually true.